# how to do I safely iterate over a collection inside a thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a java / blazeds app that keeps an array "**_games**" which is 2 players subscribed to the same blazeds topic. The issue as I see is less than 40% of connection attempts succeed, so far my efforts at debugging the issue have been unsuccessful - it seems to throw silently , and the behaviour is random except that the 1st pair seem to have more luck connecting than subsequent attempts.I have seen a **ConcurrentModificationException** and what I have read on the topic suggests my code has problems with concurrency.

In this case I'm iterating over a array "_games" inside a thread, I'd like to know how I can do this safely as other clients will be attempting to access this variable at random times.

**Update** #2:

While debugging the for loop inside the thread, it appears the current item is always the same so the iterator is not advancing and or being reset by a subsequent request so i always = 0 , or if use a for(Game g : _games) , then g is always the 1st item in the array.

thanks!

```
public class GameService {

private static List<Game> _games;
private static GameServiceThread thread;


public GameService(MessageTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

public Game CreateOrJoinGame(GamePlayer player)
{

    Game currentGame = new Game();
    boolean isFull = false;
    for (Game g: _games)
    {

        ArrayCollection myCollection = g.myCollection;
        currentGame = g;
        if(!g.IsFull())
        {
            myCollection.add(player);

            if(g.IsFull())
            {
                isFull = true;
                currentGame.myCollection = myCollection;
                System.out.print("User Count..." + myCollection.size() + "\n");
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if(isFull)
    {
        return currentGame;
    }
    else
    {
        Game creator = CreateGame(player);
        return creator;
    }
}


public void start() {
     if (thread == null) {
        if(_games == null)
        {
          _games = new ArrayList<Game>();
        }        
            thread = new GameServiceThread(this.template);
            thread.start();
     }
}
public void AddPlayer(GamePlayer player)
{
    _allPlayers.add(player);
}
```

//nested static thread class

```
public static class GameServiceThread extends Thread {

        @Override
    public void run() {

        this.running = true;
        while (this.running) 
        {
            for (Game g: _games)
            {
                 //do work
            }

        }
     }


    private void sendGameUpdate(final Game game) {}
```

This service is registered in flex-servlet just for info, although I don't think this is my issue.

```
<bean id="gameFeedService" class="com.acme.services.GameService">
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultMessageTemplate" />
    <flex:remoting-destination />
</bean>
```

**Edit**: Added some code for how new games get added. I iterate over _games inside the GameService class and also inside the GameServiceThread. Firstly as new clients send a remote game object to the service, and I iterate inside the same collection to send each game recipient a message. Inside each game is a collection which I use to determine if the Game is full or not - if it is a new Game() is created.

Comment: How do games get added to the `_games` list?

Comment: Added an edit - let me know if you need more info @KeithRandall

Answer (score 1):

You could synchronize on the list itself.

```
    @Override
public void run() {

    this.running = true;
    while (this.running) 
    {
        synchronized (_games) {
            for (Game g: _games) {
             //do work
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to `synchronize` access to the `_games` list.

Here's a [Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) tutorial on docs.oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using a thread safe List, for example:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

Check [ArrayList javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for further informations.

Comment: This will only work if the only synchronization you want is on the operations of the list itself (add, remove, etc.). That is, you don't need any code sections in your program to be executed atomically.

Comment: @xagyg - You are right, it could solve a problem but could not be enough to solve all.

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized(_games) {            
    for (Game g: _games)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

OR

```
synchronized(getClass()) {            
    for (Game g: _games)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

will both work.

Depending on what you are doing in sendGameUpdate, you may have to synchornize on the same object there as well.